# How can I query the results of a query in Server Explorer in Visual Studio?

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2013, server-explorer, subquery

I can get the results of a Stored Proc from Visual Studio by following these steps:

```
0) Select View > Server Explorer

1) Locate the Data Connection that contains the SP of interest.

2) Right-click the SP and select Execute; if any args are required, it will allow you to populate those in a dialog and then proceed with the execution
```

Provided that you have provided valid args (and the SP returns data), the results will display in a grid in a T-SQL Results tab.

Now, though, what if you want to query that "dataset" that has been returned, such as to sum the values of a particular column - can that be done right there from within Visual Studio.Server Explorer.T-SQL? If so, how?

### UPDATE

I believe Khazratbek, but I can only get this far in a New Query instantiated by right-clicking the Tables folder beneath the Data Connection:

```
SELECT SUM(QtyShipped), SUM(QtyOrdered) FROM CPSData.
```

...the options available as a drop down following that final "." do not contain the results of the Stored Proc (SQLQuery1.sql).

Is it really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server Explorer -. Right click on Tables -> New query. Write your query (you may select from your SP execution results) and just click on triangle sign. Sorry, if I misunderstand your exact question.

Comment: How are the SP execution results referenced? The results from the SP are in a tab named "SQLQuery1.sql", but the dropdown list which appears after I write "SELECT * FROM" after selecting "New Query" does not contain "SQLQuery1.sql"...

Comment: Have you tried that?
<code>Declare @tablevar table(col1,..);
insert into @tablevar(col1,..) exec MyStoredProc 'param1', 'param2';
SELECT col1, col2 FROM @tablevar</code>

Comment: I don't understand your comment,, but I have been able to run queries based on your answer.

Comment: My comment is using some temporary table, which takes results from stored procedure, and you may may selects from that table. I will add one more answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's think that your stored procedures gives you logins and passwords of users:

```
select login, password from users;
```

You are taking one million result, for example. And you don't need to change your stored procedure, but you want to make some job with your results (selecting in some order, changing the order, select by some condition, so on).
Let's continue. Your stored procedure gives you a two column: it is column login and password. So we may consider the results of your SP execution as some table. To work with your result do next steps:

*Server Explorer* -> Your_database_connection -> Right click on *Tables* -> *New query*

Then write the following code there:

```
Declare @temporary_table_variable table(login varchar, password varchar); --or without datatypes 
insert into @temporary_table_variable(login, password) exec MyStoredProc; 
SELECT * from @temporary_table_variable where id > 1000; --it is just a simple example
```

Hope it helps